# adding new line in the description of the dialog in wix localization string element

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm new to WiX, and using WiX v3.0.

I'm using the **WixUI_Advanced** dialogs. I customized `InstallDirDlg` description by adding a `.wxl` (WiX localization) file.

However, I cannot add a newline in the description.

I tried following to get a new line,

```
1. <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription">Hello\nHai</String>

2. <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription">Hello
   Hai</String>

3. <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription">Hello</String>
   <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">Hai</String>

4. <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription">Hello&#13;&#10;Hai</String>
```

But, none of those options work. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you've found a bug in the .wxl handling in the WiX toolset. I would expect option number 4 or the following to work:

```
<String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription"><![CDATA[Hello
Hai]]></String>
```

At this point, you'll probably be best served opening a [WiX toolset bug](http://wixtoolset.org/bugs). You might even consider enlisting in the code and trying to root cause the issue to help get the bug fixed. Seems like it should work.